# optimize the comparison in two lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists of object:

Customer And Employee

I need to check if there is at least 1 Client with the same name as an employee.

Currently I have:

```
client.ForEach(a =>
            {
                if (employee.Any(m => m.Name == a.Name && m.FirstName==a.FirstName)
                {
                    // OK TRUE
                }
            });
```

can I improve reading by doing it in another way?

Comment: You could try joining the two lists together on the Name and FirstName properties.

Answer (score 2):

why won't you check it before hand using join?

```
var mergedClients = Client.Join(listSFull,
                x => new { x.Name, x.FirstName},
                y => new { Name = y.Name, FirstName= y.FirstName},
                (x, y) => new { x, y }).ToList();
```

and then iterate over the new collection:

```
mergedClients.ForEach(a =>
//your logic
```

Only disadvantage of this approach (if it bothers you) is that null values will not be included.

Comment: This is not exactly the same as the question. You are doing an inner join he is doing a semi join (Any match in inner list)

Comment: @Magnus elaborate please, could you provide an example where a difference in the result could be seen? (I don't understand what you mean but am interested)

Comment: If `listSFull` has multiple entries of the same value your code would return every hit , the code in the question only check if there is any existence.

Comment: he is doing the so called semi-join on every client. So why won't he loop over a joined list from the beginning? there would be no need of any condition from the first place.

Comment: @Magnus ah, you mean e.g. when clients are non-distinct and employees are, and there is a match on duplicated client

Comment: Consider the difference between: `new[]{"a","b"}.Join(new[]{"a","a", "b"},x => x, x => x, (x, y) => x)` and `new[]{"a","b"}.Where(x => new[]{"a","a", "b"}.Any (y => x == y))`

Answer (score 1):

I would go either with Join

```
var isDuplicated = clients.Join(employees, 
       c => new { c.Name, c.FirstName }, 
       e => new { e.Name, e.FirstName },
       (c, e) => new { c, e })
       .Any();
```

or Intersect

```
var clientNames = clients.Select(c => new { c.Name, c.FirstName });
var employeeNames = employees.Select(e => new { e.Name, e.FirstName });
var isDuplicated = clientNames.Intersect(employeeNames).Any();
```

Both of `Join` and `Intersect` use hashing, and are close to O(n).

Note: equality (and hash code) of anonymous objects (`new { , }`) is evaluated as for a value type. I.e. two anonymous objects are equal (implies have same hash code) when all their fields are equal.

=== EDIT: Ok, I was interested myself (hope your question was about performance :P)

```
[TestMethod]
public void PerformanceTest()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var clients = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
            .Select(_ => new Person { FirstName = $"{random.Next()}",      
                                      LastName = $"{random.Next()}" })
            .ToList();

    var employees = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
            .Select(_ => new Person { FirstName = $"{random.Next()}", 
                                      LastName = $"{random.Next()}" })
            .ToList();

    var joinElapsedMs = MeasureAverageElapsedMs(() =>
        {
            var isDuplicated = clients.Join(employees,
                    c => new { c.FirstName, c.LastName },
                    e => new { e.FirstName, e.LastName },
                    (c, e) => new { c, e })
                    .Any();
        });

    var intersectElapsedMs = MeasureAverageElapsedMs(() =>
        {
            var clientNames = clients.Select(c => new { c.FirstName, c.LastName });
            var employeeNames = employees.Select(e => new { e.FirstName, e.LastName });
            var isDuplicated = clientNames.Intersect(employeeNames).Any();
        });

    var anyAnyElapsedMs = MeasureAverageElapsedMs(() =>
        {
            var isDuplicated = clients.Any(c => employees.Any(
                    e => c.FirstName == e.FirstName && c.LastName == e.LastName));
        });

    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(joinElapsedMs)}: {joinElapsedMs}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(intersectElapsedMs)}: {intersectElapsedMs}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(anyAnyElapsedMs)}: {anyAnyElapsedMs}");
}

private static double MeasureAverageElapsedMs(Action action) =>
    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => MeasureElapsedMs(action)).Average();

private static long MeasureElapsedMs(Action action)
{
    var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    action();
    return stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
joinElapsedMs: 5.9
intersectElapsedMs: 3.5
anyAnyElapsedMs: 3185.8
```

Note: any-any is O(n^2) - (in worst case) every employee is iterated per each iterated client.