# How to compare two lists on a combination of two properties and select a row which has mismatch in the third property?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linqpad

I want to compare the following two lists on a combination of two properties (Country and City).

When compared, India-Chennai is present in both the lists and have the same value (1). Similarly, UK-London also is present in both the lists and have the same value (3). However, though USA-New York is present on both the lists, their values are not matching (2 in list1 and 5 in list 2).

Please help me write the shortest possible linq expression to select only '2-USA-New York' from list1 as its value is not matching with list2 ('5-USA-New York').

```
void Main()
{
    List<A> list1 = new List<A> {
        new A { Country = "India", City = "Chennai", Value = 1 },
        new A { Country = "USA", City = "New York", Value = 2 },
        new A { Country = "UK", City = "London", Value = 3 }
    };

    List<A> list2 = new List<A> {
        new A { Country = "India", City = "Chennai", Value = 1 },
        new A { Country = "USA", City = "New York", Value = 5 },
        new A { Country = "UK", City = "London", Value = 3 }
    };

    list1.Dump();
    list2.Dump();
}

class A
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see here on how to create minimal complete, verifiable https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicated `{ Country, City }` pairs in your lists:

```
var list1Missmatched = list1
    .Join(list2, 
          left => new { left.Country, left.City },
          right => new { right.Country, right.City }, 
          (left, right) => new { left, right })
    .Where(x => x.left.Value != x.right.Value)
    .Select(x => x.left)
    .ToList();
```

This works, because in the `leftList.Join(rightList, leftMatchBy, rightMatchBy, matchedPairResultSelector)` we use 'anonymous object' as the key to be matched by. Equality (and hash code) of anonymous objects behaves as for a value type, i.e. `new { Foo = 1 }` and `new { Foo = 1 }` are equal and have same hash code, even though they are two different instances.

`Join` builds a hash table out of (matchByKey, listItem) pairs, which allows for almost linear algorithmic complexity - O(n) (in contrast with the `Where(Any())` solution, which is of a quadratic complexity - O(n^2)).
If you are interested, recently I wrote a small [performance test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301727/9678775) comparing these two approaches.

Comment: The following also worked. Just tried now:

list1.Where(a => list2.Any(b => (b.Country == a.Country && b.City == a.City && b.Value != a.Value))).Dump();

Comment: sorry for the formatting, am writing from mobile phone during a meeting :D Will also provide some explanation why it works & what's going on once I get back to my PC

Comment: No worries :) It was very much helpful

Comment: @VladiPavelka ...let me give you a hand with that formatting... ;)

Answer (score 3):

I realize this has been answered satisfactorily already, but here's an alternative solution.

This may be a little more intuitive / easy to understand for some, since it avoids the whole *join*-concept, and just looks for *any row matching the current row* instead.

You can however, expect a solution like this solution to be slower than the above, especially for longer / more complex lists, so keep that in mind, and use it only for simpler cases.

```
var result = list1
              .Where(rowFromFirst => 
                       list2.Any(rowFromSecond => 
                                    rowFromSecond.Country == rowFromFirst.Country &&
                                    rowFromSecond.City == rowFromFirst.City && 
                                    rowFromSecond.Value != rowFromFirst.Value));
```